# Why does a Zavah bring a Korban?

Tags: sin, korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, niddah

Does anyone know why the *Zavah* (a woman who experiences certain menstrual bleeding outside her regular cycle) brings a sin offering on the eighth day after the bleeding ceases? (Leviticus 15:29).